# Convert from double to long without Round Java

Tags: java, double, long-integer

I'm trying to convert a random double to a long without rounding or truncating it.
First I change the double to a string, to know how many decimal places there are and then I change the value to long.
My problem is that the number of the last decimal place is not always correct and I don't know the reason and how I can change it.
Here is the code:

```
            double z=(double) myRandom(1, 20);
    long test;
    String s = Double.toString(z);
    test=(long) (Math.pow(10, s.length()-s.indexOf(".")-1)*z);
    System.out.println("z: "+z);    
    System.out.println("double converted to long: "+test);
```

And that's the output:

d: 19.625014811604743

double converted to long: 19625014811604744

d: 9.143326452202839

double converted to long: 9143326452202838

d: 5.8964228376511105

double converted to long: 58964228376511104

d: 15.045936360299917

double converted to long: 15045936360299918

d: 14.147950026532694

double converted to long: 14147950026532694

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: `Double.toString(double)` does not necessarily output what you might expect from just blindly printing each digit of the same `double`. It does some magic to try to get rid of funky repeating digit binary representations.

Comment: Floating point rounding errors. Why don't you just take the string you have, replace `"."` with `""`, and then parse that into a `long`? Or, you could go double -> BigDecimal -> (multiple BigDecimal by the appropriate factor of 10) -> BigInteger. That will also work if your code changes to allow huge doubles.

Comment: It honestly seems like the OP is just trying to implement `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Why do you care about the accuracy to 16 digits of a random number?

Comment: @PeterLawrey +1 from an "it's just got to work" perspective, but I commend the OP for seeing something weird and wondering why it would be like that.

Comment: @yshavit It would be like that because you only have 16 digits of accuracy and when you perform a calculation the last digit can be slightly too high or too low.  This is due to the fact that double cannot accurately represent any of the values the OP mentions.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yup, I posted an answer with that a few minutes ago. I was just pointing out that it's good of the OP to not just shrug and say "eh, good enough" but actually ask why it happens.

Answer (score 3):

Editing your current implementation:

```
double z=(double) myRandom(1, 20);
String s = Double.toString(z); //convert to string (edited thanks to comments)
s = s.replaceAll(".", ""); //remove the period
long test = Long.parseLong(s); //convert to long
```

Or if you just want a random `Long` I would recommend using `Random.nextLong()` instead.

Comment: Why use `String s = z + "";` over `String s = Double.toString(z)`?

Comment: No reason. That's always been my preferred way to convert to `String` in Java, but using `Double.toString` would work just as well.

Comment: Just an fyi, you should use Double.toString()... String s = z + ""; creates a temp string while toString() does not.

Comment: @Grammin is `""` the temp string you're talking about?

Comment: I believe "" gets taken from the string pool, but z gets converted into a string using String.valueOf and then you create another string by adding String.valueOf(z) to "";

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the heads up; I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to obtain a random long number, then I would strongly recommend using Random.nextLong() instead.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have pointed out how you can fix this, but your other question was *why* it happens. The answer to that is floating-point error.

Floating-point numbers consist of three main parts: a sign (+ or -), a mantissa and an exponent. Essentially, the number is represented as essentially `(sign) (mantissa) * 2^(exponent)` (but not exactly -- see links below). As you can imagine, not all numbers fit snugly into this representation; some have to be approximated. The quintessential example is one-tenth, which in binary has an infinite repeating sequence and so has to be approximated in doubles.

At high values -- those greater than the mantissa can represnt -- there are some integers that can't be represented exactly. This happens at 2^53; any number greater than this has to be approximated, and the numbers you mention are such examples.

You don't even need `Math.pow` to demonstrate this; literals will do just fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  double d1 = 19.625014811604743;
  double d2 = 19625014811604743.0;

  System.out.println(d1);
  System.out.println(d2);
}
```

This will print:

```
19.625014811604743
1.9625014811604744E16
```

Notice the 4 at the end of that second value. 19625014811604744 is the closest number to 19625014811604743 that can be represented as a double.

Related reading:

- http://floating-point-gui.de/ Good introduction
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary64 A bit more detail, about doubles specifically
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html A bit dense, but important once you get the hang of things
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Answer (score 0):

```
test=(long) (Math.pow(10, s.length()-s.indexOf(".")-1)*z);
```

Is messing up your double in the arithmetic, try something like this:

```
public long convertDoubleToLong(double d){
  String str = Double.toString(d);
  return Long.parseLong(str.replace(".", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this...

```
double x = 19.625014811604743;
while(x % 1 != 0) x *= 10;
long y = (long) x;
System.out.println("x: "+ x + " y: "+ y);
```

Comment: Couldn't repeatedly multiplying by 10 exacerbate precision issues?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to round a double number by dropping the fractional part, you can see this example:

```
Long doubleToLong(double dAmount) {
    return (long) (int) dAmount;
}
```